# Rails STI Intermittent Error - Invalid single-table inheritance type: HomeLineup is not a subclass of HomeLineup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sti

I'm using STI in my Lineup model:

```
class Lineup < ApplicationRecord
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Lineup")
  end
end
```

and I have:

```
class HomeLineup < Lineup

end
```

and

```
class AwayLineup < Lineup

end
```

and

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord

  include PublicActivity::Common

  has_one :home_lineup
  has_one :away_lineup

end
```

.

**Sometimes** I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid single-table inheritance type: HomeLineup is not a subclass of HomeLineup):
    43: 
    44:           <div class="media align-items-center" style="margin: auto;">
    45:             <span class="align-items-center text-center" style="/* font-size:11px; */text-transform:uppercase;margin-right: 30px;display: inline-flex;width: auto;"><%= activity.match.championship.name %></span>
    46:             <span class="mr-2"><%= activity.match.home_lineup.club.acronym %></span>
    47:             <%= link_to activity.match.home_lineup.club, class: "avatar rounded-circle mr-3", style: "background:none !important;width: 20px;" do %>
    48:                 <%= image_tag(url_for_club_badge(activity.match.home_lineup.club)) %>
    49:               <% end %>                   

app/views/public_activity/substitution/_create.html.erb:46:in `_app_views_public_activity_substitution__create_html_erb__1114711258957038838_69831017880240'
```

The problem is that I don't see when I'm trying to use HomeLineup as a sub class of HomeLineup.

Whenever I got the error, I restart the server and everything will be fine for while.

What might be causing this error?

My setup is:

- ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 5.2.2.1

Regards,
David

Comment: Why do you have a `self.model_name` method in `Lineup`?

Comment: @muistooshort I actually don't know any more, this is a old code. But I think that is to not have to define routes for all subclasses.